# Get background colour and set that colour as list tile gradient - react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, user-interface

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UoZO.png)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UoZO.png

Am new to react native from Native android development,

Am trying to achieve the above UI in react native,

Which is basically get flatList Tile's current background color and set as gradient of that particular tile.

Can anyone please help me on this to achieve ?

Answer (score 1):

You can make the background for the item blurred using `@react-native-community/blur` like this:

```
import { BlurView } from "@react-native-community/blur";


<BlurView style={{
          position: "absolute",
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          bottom: 0,}}
          blurType="light"
          blurAmount={10}
          reducedTransparencyFallbackColor="white"
        />
```

Comment: looks like a solution for my question, Can you please share me an workaround or an sample

Comment: Can you upload your code on github and share it with me.

Comment: Thanks @louay I did a workaround and made it work, Do u know any other libraries like this ?

Comment: To create a blur unfortunately there's no other libraries until now, Please mark it as a correct answer and if you have any other question I'm happy to help :D